# how to create activemodel instance variables like field :foo as done in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm looking for some information on how to define instance variables the way mongoid does by having

```
field :foo 
field :bar
```

at the top of my model class. It seems to only fire static or class methods and I cant seem to populate instance variables from a class method obviously. I haven't been able to figure out how it is happening from the mongoid code. I want to define a list of items there and assign them to a class level list.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ruby's `attr_accessor` method.